# Camel streaming tokenizeXML on routes gives org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0)

Tags: xml, apache-camel, saxparser

While running a route that parses an XML file in streaming mode I get the exception: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

```
from(routeUrl).routeId("FtpRuleId"+ftpRule.getId())
.setProperty("FILTER_NON_XML_CHARS", constant(true))
.split().tokenizeXML("RECORD").streaming()
    .marshal().xmljson()
    .process(recordProcessor)
.end();
```

The route works fine but on some files throws the SAXParseException midway through processing the file. I tried setting Exchange property FILTER_NON_XML_CHARS but this did not seem to have any effect.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem wasn't with the `tokenizeXML("RECORD")` method but with the `marshal().xmljson()`

I created a processor to strip the bad characters using the method described here: http://blog.mark-mclaren.info/2007/02/invalid-xml-characters-when-valid-utf8_5873.html

```
from(routeUrl).routeId("FtpRuleId"+ftpRule.getId())
.setProperty("FILTER_NON_XML_CHARS", constant(true))
.split().tokenizeXML("RECORD").streaming()
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .process(stripInvalidXmlProcessor)
    .marshal().xmljson()
    .process(recordProcessor)
.end();
```

This solved the issues. There may be support for this already in Camel but I couldn't find it.